# How to count/increment the current number of occurances of a table column in a MS SQL select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which looks like this:

```
id | name| fk_something
----------------
0  | 25  | 3
1  | 25  | 2
2  | 23  | 1
```

and I want to add another column with a number which increments everytime row `name` occurs, e.g.:

```
id | name| fk_something| n
--------------------------
0  | 25  | 3           | 1
1  | 25  | 2           | 2
2  | 23  | 1           | 1
```

I'm not really sure how to achieve this. Using `count()` I will only  get the total number of occurances of `name` but I want to increment `n` so that I have a distinct value for each row.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `row_number()` :

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as n
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `COUNT` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    fk_something,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) n
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    id;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: This shows the total number of occurances for every row (in my example n = 2 for id 0 and 1). The solution from @yogesh-sharma is what I was actually looking for. Thanks nevertheless.

Comment: @spcial My answer generates the output you expect, and I suggest using `COUNT` over `ROW_NUMBER`, as the former specifically counts rows, which seems to be what you want here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Run this code on data that has duplicates and compare to `row_number()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff But I was assuming that there are no duplicates.